# Why no article in "zu Bild A / auf Bild A"?

Tags: article

In the exercise book I've met the following sentence:

> Das ovale Gesicht passt zu Bild A.

Question: Why "**Bild**" doesn't have any article here? To find examples just google for "zu Bild A".

Comment: You could consider "Bild A" a *name*. Names don't normally come with articles.

Comment: That's BTW the same in English.

Answer (score 10):

If a noun is followed by a cardinal number or letter (or combination
thereof), there is often no definite article in front of the construction.
This holds in particular for printed material or other media:

- zu Bild A
- in Kapitel 5
- in Anhang B/2
- auf Seite 25
- in Folge 7
- in Akt III
- wegen Theorem 3.5

Omitting the article is not a hard and fast rule, however. For instance, you can find both

- in Haus (Nr.) 10
- in Abteilung 3

and

- im [= in dem] Haus (Nr.) 10
- in der Abteilung 3

and the version *with* article even seems to be *more* common.

Note the difference between cardinal numbers on the one side and titles
or ordinal numbers on the other side: While there is usually no article in

- in Kapitel 5

the article is mandatory in

- im [= in dem] fünften Kapitel
- im [= in dem] Kapitel "Adjektive und Adverbien"

Comment: Didn't you mean to say the version *without* article seems to be more common?

Comment: @RHa no. The version with article has in fact *more* Google hits. (I was also surprised.)

Answer (score 1):

Either *Bild A* is already uniquely defined, then *dem* (definite article) is not necessary and *einem* (indefinite articel) is simply wrong, since there is only one.

Or there are several *Bild A*, then a typical construction would be

> .. dem Bild A, das auf Seite 7 steht.

The article is also likely to be merged with the *zu*, giving *zum*.

Comment: _Either Bild A is already uniquely defined, then dem (definite article) is not necessary_ What about _die Sonne_, _die Erde_, _die Zahl 3_, _der höchste Berg der Welt_, _die Gattung Rattus_, _der Eiffelturm_?